# ¿Superlativo de "frío"?

Tags: superlativos

Ayer, en un *spa*, uno de mis vástagos dijo que el agua de la piscina fría estaba "friísima".
Él quería decir que el agua estaba muy fría, y de manera natural cogió el sufijo "-ísima" del superlativo, se lo colocó a una supuesta raíz "fri-" de "frío", y santas pascuas... pero eso no es correcto, claro. ¿O sí?

Igual que tenemos "calentísimo" para "caliente", o "fresquísimo" para "fresco", ¿existe superlativo para "frío"? ¿Cuál? Y si no existe, ¿hay alguna razón etimológica para ello?

Comment: Habría dicho  la _piscina estaba  `superfria`_

Comment: [re](https://dle.rae.es/re-?m=form)frío?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pues es totalmente correcto. La verdad que no tenía muchas dudas pero por si acaso lo he buscado. Hay dos superlativos, uno es *friísimo* como dice tu hijo y otro la forma culta *frigidísimo* con escaso uso hoy día.

Tenemos una entrada en el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=fr%EDo):

> **frío -a.** ‘Que tiene una temperatura inferior a la ordinaria del ambiente’. Tiene dos superlativos válidos: *frigidísimo* (del lat.
>   *frigidissimus*) y *friísimo*, formado sobre *frío* y más frecuente en el
>   uso (→ -ísimo, 2f y 4): *«Estábamos sumergidos en un denso vapor de
>   agua frigidísima»* (LpzHaro *Yo* [Esp. 1930]); *«Me dio un beso friísimo»*
>   (Alatriste *Vivir* [Méx. 1985]).

Siguiendo el enlace de [-ísimo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=UByFr5964D6oCGp9V4) que encontramos en la entrada anterior vuelve a aparecer *friísimo* en el ejemplo de como se añade este superlativo a un adjetivo terminado en *-ío/-ía*:

> f) Los adjetivos terminados en los hiatos *-ío/-ía* pierden la última
>   vocal: de *frío*, *friísimo*; de *impía*, *impiísima*.

Incluso está en la entrada del DLE de frío:

> **[frío, a](https://dle.rae.es/?id=IUteOxn)**
>
> `Del lat. frigĭdus.`
>
> Sup. irreg. frigidísimo, cult.; reg. friísimo.

También se ha preguntado por Twitter y esto es lo que respondío la [RAE](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/282068583721349121?lang=es):

> @Scarlettpaola #RAEconsultas El superlativo de FRÍO es FRIÍSIMO o MUY
>   FRÍO; la forma culta FRIGIDÍSIMO apenas se usa ya http://ow.ly/ghtVP

Comment: ¿Y por qué no **álgido**?

Comment: @Jdamian pues también podía ser, o *gélido*

Comment: **álgido** y **gélido** son sinónimos de **friísimo**, pero no son el superlativo de frío. Otro sinónimo es **glacial**.

Answer (score 7):

Ciertamente "frigidísimo" es un vocablo con poco uso actualmente y más aún por la semejanza polisémica con la referencia léxica "frígido", el cual es un adjetivo que atribuye más hacia una actitud o incapacidad de experimentar placer sexual. Aunque la DRAE define formalmente "frígido" como el superlativo de frío.

Comment: Yo siempre he pensado y usado *frígido* como el superlativo de frío, aunque reconozco y a veces uso *friísimo*.  *Frigidísimo* me parece casi un doble superlativ.